# Need Lotus-Formula code to full in current date in particular format

Tags: lotus, lotus-formula

Get current year to fill in automatically.

**The code I have creates the following:**

`"01/02/19: LastName: "`

```
FIELD Comments := @Left (@Text(@Today); "2018") + "18: " + @Right(@Name([CN];@UserName); " ") + ": ";
```

Would like to have the "/19" (year) to automatically use the current year instead of having it hard coded. I'm sure this is ridiculously easy but I'm not a programmer. Please let me know what the code needs to be

Answer (score 2):

This should work for most of locales (language specific settings):

```
_Year := @Text(@Year(@Today));
_Today := @ReplaceSubstring(@Text(@Today; "D0S0"); _Year; @Right(_Year; 2));
FIELD Comments := _Today + ": " + @Right(@Name([CN];@UserName); " ") + ": ";
```

It replaces the 4 year's digits with the last 2 year's digits.